# How to import data from excel file into sql server DB by script

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to import data from Excel into SQL.

I saw all kinds of answers on Google, but I didn't really find the right answer
I would really appreciate any help on this matter...

I have an excel file in a folder and I want to create a script that will load all the data from this excel file into a dedicated table in my DB
The script should be written in SQL Server
Does anyone have a simple way to do this?

I try this code:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

USE Diyur;
GO
SELECT * INTO Data_dq
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\File.xls', [Sheet1$]);
GO
```

But I get this error:

```
Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 The OLE DB provider 
"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered. Blockquote
```

Comment: Why "script"? If you use the import/export wizard, the last step before you load that information will give an option to save that process as a SSIS package. You can then run that package whenever you want. Is that sufficient?

Comment: @SMor - becouse I need to run it on many server... So I want to create only script that do id and then I run it many times

Comment: Look at `openrowset`

Comment: Importing Excel using any system is unreliable. One wierd character or empty cell and the entire thing breaks.

Comment: @Stu - I try it. but I get an error. look at the question

Comment: Can I suggest you google the error. There are a million solutions. Unfortunately you have a lot to go through

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I tried milion solutions in google, but I still in the problem....

Comment: @Ayal the solution to your error is something you can Google for and find many good explanations. This is really far too broad a topic and SO is not a tutorial site, there are many good sources already.

Comment: If the group that manages your database servers has not or will not install the appropriate drivers to use openrowset, then you simply CANNOT do this using tsql. Perhaps you should discuss this with that group? An alternative is to use BCP with a text or csv file.

Comment: @SMor - Yes... maybe that's really my problem... How to use with bcp? I found bcp only to export file

Comment: My advice is: don't try this. It's suprisingly difficult to do what you want. First getting the right driver installed, then dealing with bad data that people put into the excel sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many google searches and my many attempts I found the correct code:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = '

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
( [Field1] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Field2] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Field3] nvarchar(max) NULL ); 


BULK INSERT #TempTable  FROM ''<FullPath>\FileName.csv'' WITH --if the path is in the network - need to write the Full-path of the drive
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
MAXERRORS = 10000,
KEEPNULLS, 
ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'',
FIRSTROW = 2,
CODEPAGE = ''1255''
);

select * from #TempTable
Insert into TableNameInDB(Field1,Field2,Field3)
select * from #TempTable
'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```